# incomprehensible random variable output

Tags: python, random

Here is my code with an explanation to what i'm looking for

```
#generate a list of variable size between 2 and 6
#each item in the list must contain a float> = 1.5 and <= a 4 and the sum of each item in the list must be >= 8 and <= 12

from random import randint, uniform
import time
NombrePassage = randint(2,6)
passage = []
generated = True
x = 0

while generated:
    heureTotal = 0
    for i in range(NombrePassage):
        tmp = round(uniform(1.5,4),2)
        passage.append(tmp)
        heureTotal = heureTotal + passage[i]
        print(heureTotal)
        time.sleep(0.5) 
    if  heureTotal <= 12.0 and heureTotal >= 8.0:
        print("FINDED")
        generated= False


print(*passage, sep="\n")
```

But the output is weird. Sometime it works perfectly!

Other times the output is cyclical. For example:

```
6
3.27
6.6899999999999995
9.33
11.68
14.709999999999999
17.0
3.27
6.6899999999999995
9.33
11.68
14.709999999999999
17.0
3.27
6.6899999999999995
9.33
11.68
14.709999999999999
17.0
```

The condition is reached but the program does not validate it.

I didn't understand what happened!

(I'm new in dev, and sorry for bad English!)

Comment: "the condition is reached but the program does not validate it" - What makes you think the condition is reached?

Comment: Do you think 7.37 is greater than or equal to 8.0?

Comment: you never reset passage  if you fail to find a good set, so it then just loops over the items you've already added each time.

Comment: I modified the post to change the output, here the condition is reached

Comment: Do you think 17.0 is less than or equal to 12.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `passage` each time you loop:

```
while generated:
    passage = []
    heureTotal = 0
    for i in range(NombrePassage):
        ...
```

Comment: p.s. it's almost impossible to have 2 random numbers that add up to exactly 8;  if NombreRange = 2, you will be waiting for a very long time.  in that case you should just manually set each element to '4'.

Comment: It works fine, but sometimes it doesn't find a valid list and has to start again..

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of problems with your code:

- You keep adding to the end of `passage`, but once you complete a number of iterations, you really want to start a new list if the goal wasn't met
- You have very tricky edge conditions, 2 * 4 is only just 8, so if you're trying to find a list with only 2 values, they need to be exactly 4 to add up to 8 (since you don't allow values greater than 4). Similarly, if you're trying to find list with 6 values, they need to be 2 or less on average.

If you add `passage = []` in the loop and remove the wait `time.sleep(0.5)`, you'll find your program works.

It could have been a lot simpler though:

```
from random import randint, uniform

numbers = []
n = randint(2, 6)
while not 8 <= sum(numbers) <= 12:
    numbers = [round(uniform(1.5, 4), 2) for _ in range(n)]
print(numbers)
```